# How to remove a property from JObject in C#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a JObject instance with the following key/values:

```
{ "filed1": "4", "filed2": "name", "filed3": null, "filed4": "2021-09-20T00:00:00Z", "filed5": null, "filed6": null, "filed7": null }
```

I need to remove a property, i.e. `filed1`. How can I do that in C#??

Answer (score 7):

Try [`JObject.Remove(string)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Remove.htm).

```cs
JObject o = new JObject(
    new JProperty("filed1", 4),
    new JProperty("filed2", null),
    new JProperty("filed3", null),
    new JProperty("filed4", new DateTime(2021, 9, 20)),
    new JProperty("filed5", null),
    new JProperty("filed6", null),
    new JProperty("filed7", null),
);

Console.WriteLine(o);
// Outputs:
// {
//   "filed1": 4,
//   "filed2": null,
//   "filed3": null,
//   "filed4": "2021-09-20T00:00:00",
//   "filed5": null,
//   "filed6": null,
//   "filed7": null
// }

o.Remove("filed1");
Console.WriteLine(o);
// Outputs:
// {
//   "filed2": null,
//   "filed3": null,
//   "filed4": "2021-09-20T00:00:00",
//   "filed5": null,
//   "filed6": null,
//   "filed7": null
// }
```